# Meraki firewall MX64 how to do two IP seperated inbound NATs

Tags: nat, meraki

I need to achieve the same result of these two commands which are on Cisco CLI but on Meraki GUI

so we have two valid public IP address(81.1.1.30,31) on outside interface of MX64

both of 'em want to be forwarded to two seperate Webservers

```
Switch6500(config)#ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.50 tcp 80 81.1.1.30 tcp 80

Switch6500(config)#ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.51 tcp 80 81.1.1.31 tcp 80
```

How can I do that? I couldn't find a place to specify what **outside IP+Port combination** I want to be forwarded to this Private(local) IP add+port combination, all they have is either interface(uplink) alone or IP address without port alone

thx

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "1:1 NAT": https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/NAT_and_Port_Forwarding/Port_Forwarding_and_NAT_Rules_on_the_MX

Comment: as weird as it is, this feature is not in 1:1, it's on 1:m part of this switch
for doing IP:Port pair to IP:port pair

Comment: Strange, it's in 1:1 on one of my MX64's I just checked. Welcome to Meraki!